# Python XML Parsing Algorithm Speed

Tags: python, xml, optimization, flask, lxml

I'm currently parsing a large XML file of the following form in a python-flask webapp on heroku:

```
<book name="bookname">
  <volume n="1" name="volume1name">
    <chapter n="1">
       <li n="1">li 1 content</li>
       <li n="2">li 2 content</li>
    </chapter/>
    <chapter n="2">
       <li n="1">li 1 content</li>
       <li n="2">li 2 content</li>
    </chapter/>
  </volume>
  <volume n="2" name="volume2name">
    <chapter n="1">
       <li n="1">li 1 content</li>
       <li n="2">li 2 content</li>
    </chapter/>
    <chapter n="2">
       <li n="1">li 1 content</li>
       <li n="2">li 2 content</li>
    </chapter/>
  </volume>
</book>
```

The code that I use to parse, analyze it, and display it through Flask is as the following:

```
from lxml import etree
file = open("books/filename.xml")
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse(file, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

def getChapter(volume, chapter):
    i = 0
    data = []
    while True:
        try:
            data.append(root[volumeList().index(volume)][chapter-1][i].text)
        except IndexError:
            break
        i += 1
    if data == []:
        data = None
    return data

def volumeList():
    data = tree.xpath('//volume/@name')
    return data

def chapterCount(volume):
    currentChapter = 1
    count = 0
    while True:
        data = getChapter(volume, currentChapter)
        if data == None:
            break
        else:
            count += 1
            currentChapter += 1
    return count

def volumeNumerate():
    list = volumeList()
    i = 1
    dict = {}
    for element in list:
        dict[i] = element
        i += 1
    return dict

def render_default_values(template, **kwargs):
    chapter = getChapter(session['volume'],session['chapter'])
    count = chapterCount(session['volume'])
    return render_template(template, chapter=chapter, count=count, **kwargs)

@app.route('/<volume>/<int:chapter>')
def goto(volume, chapter):
    session['volume'] = volume
    session['chapter'] = chapter
    return render_default_values("index.html")
```

The issue that I am having is that whenever Flask is trying to render a volume with many chapters, (whenever chapterCount(session['volume']) > about 50 or so), the loading and processing of the page takes a very long time. In comparison, if the app is loading a volume that has say under 10/15 chapters, the loading is almost instantaneous, even as a live webapp.
As such, is there a good way that I can optimize this, and improve the speed and performance?
Thanks a lot!

(PS: For reference, this is my old getChapter function, that I stopped using since I don't want to refer to an individual `li' in the code and want the code to work with any generic XML file. It was considerably faster than the current getChapter function though!:

```
def OLDgetChapter(volume, chapter):
    data = tree.xpath('//volume[@name="%s"]/chapter[@n=%d]/li/text()'%(volume,chapter))
    if data == []:
        data = None
    return data
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have you heard about BeautifulSoup?**

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) does the tedious work on parsing `xml` for you, except it does it in C.

I'm positively sure this will be much faster (and much more readable):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

filename = "test.xml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filename), "xml")

def chapterCount(volume_name):
    volume = soup.find("volume", attrs={"name": volume_name})
    chapter_count = len(volume.find_all("chapter", recursive=False))
    return chapter_count

def getChapter(volume_name, chapter_number):
    volume = soup.find("volume", {"name": volume_name})
    chapter = volume.find("chapter", {"n": chapter_number})
    items = [ content for content in chapter.contents if content != "\n" ]
    return "\n".join([ item.contents[0] for item in items ])


# from now on, it's the same as your original code

def render_default_values(template, **kwargs):
    chapter = getChapter(session['volume'],session['chapter'])
    count = chapterCount(session['volume'])
    return render_template(template, chapter=chapter, count=count, **kwargs)

@app.route('/<volume>/<int:chapter>')
def goto(volume, chapter):
    session['volume'] = volume
    session['chapter'] = chapter
    return render_default_values("index.html")
```

Note that not only the `getChapter` function will be faster, but the main point is that you won't have to iterate over it for each chapter when you want to count the chapters in a specific volume through `chapterCount`. Both functions are now totally independent from each other.

**Results from both functions:**

```
>>> print(chapterCount("volume1name"))
2

>>> print(getChapter("volume1name", 2))
li 1 content
li 2 content
```

**EDIT:**

I just [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673644/beautifulsoup-counting-tags-without-parsing-deep-inside-them) to see if there could be a **faster way to count the chapters**. Stay tuned :) - **Update**: the answer is that you can use `recursive=False` to prevent BS from returning the entire tree of the elements found with `find_all`. Or, directly use `lxml`.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that you call `render_default_values` in your view. You shouldn't do that, or at least you should call this function a different way. Because "render default values" means... well, *render default values*.

Allowing this function to render something else based on a global variable (`session`) is considered not very Pythonic and can lead to spaghetti code (unknown bugs, etc).

Comment: Just note that bs would still [use `lxml` under-the-hood](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: I will try out an implementation of BS and let you know if there is a speed improvement! Thanks for the tip on the function name also!

Comment: @Jivan While testing things out, I got an idea for an alternate chapterCount function: `def chapterCount2(volume):
    chapter_numbers = [ int(x) for x in tree.xpath('//volume[@name="%s"]/chapter/@n'%(volume)) ]
    return max(chapter_numbers)`     Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Haven't tried it but I guess it could work. The only bad idea is to call getChapter in a `while True` loop to count the chapters ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about speed, instead of iterating over all volumes and chapters to find appropriate values of `name` and `n` attributes, get it in a single go with a single *xpath expression* (just noticed that this is exactly your old approach). But, instead of asking for `li`, ask for any element with `*`:

```
//volume[@name="%s"]/chapter[@n="%s"]/*/text()
```

where `%s` are placeholders for `volume` and `chapter` values passed in.

```
def getChapter(volume, chapter):
    return root.xpath('//volume[@name="%s"]/chapter[@n="%s"]/*/text()' % (volume, chapter))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> 
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
>>> tree = etree.parse(open("test.xml"), parser)
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> 
>>> volume = 'volume1name'
>>> chapter = 2
>>> 
>>> xpath = '//volume[@name="%s"]/chapter[@n="%s"]/*/text()' % (volume, chapter)
>>> root.xpath(xpath)
['li 1 content', 'li 2 content']
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, that's precisely what the OP wanted to avoid (having a fixed path expression)

Comment: Thanks for the tip that * will give any element with xpath! That will definitely let me revert to my old xpath algo (but now with *) however, I really wish the speed could be optimized a bit more.